# Switch statement with value from DB

Tags: c#, .net, switch-statement

Hi I have the scenario below - I have a table in my DB which contains zone Urls.  With each zone Url in code I call off to the zone Url to get a token.  The token expires after 30 minutes so I cannot store it in DB.

So I currently have a switch statement like below:

```
        switch (zone)
        {
            case "https://dummy.url.zone1":
                 return _zoneOneToken;
            case "https://dummy.url.zone2":
                return _zoneTwoToken;
            case "https://dummy.url.zone3":
                return _zoneThreeToken;
            default:
                const string errorMessage = "Zone not found";
                Logger.Error(errorMessage);
                throw new ApplicationException(errorMessage);
        }
```

_zoneOneToken, etc are private strings within the class that are set in another switch statement similar to above and then get for each zone using switch statement above.

I have a DAO that gets all zones from the DB - as below:

```
var allZones = zoneDao.GetAllZones();
```

`allZones` will then contain a Zone Name, The Zone Id and the Zone URL - is there anyway I can use this the ZoneUrl from this in my case statement rather than having the string values hard-coded?

If I added an Enum class which contains the ZoneIds something like below:

```
public enum ZoneEnum
{
    None = 0,
    ZoneOne = 1,
    ZoneTwo = 2,
    ZoneThree = 3
}
```

If I then used the Id from allZones and passed that too the switch statement as:

```
switch (zoneId)
{
    case ZoneEnum.ZoneOne :
     // how would I get zoneOne Url here?
     //removed rest of code for this for brevity
}
```

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes - can you expand with an answer at all - ZoneId returned would be a PK on the Table in DB - 1, 2,3 respectively

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Zone ID should be used as unique ID (possibly as a PRIMARY KEY in a corresponding table). Therefore it would be a logical candidate for your switch statement.

Such an ID should not contain any other information besides indentifying and object or record. By keeping it "neutral" you ensure that it will not have to be changed, if details (like the URL) change in future.

---

You could have a class `Zone`:

```
public class Zone
{
    public string Name { get;set; }
    public ZoneEnum Id { get; set; }
    public string URL { get; set; }

    public ZoneToken CreateToken()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

If you put all zones in a `Dictionary<ZoneEnum, Zone>`, you can get a token like this

```
Zone zone = zonesDict[ZoneEnum.ZoneTwo];
ZoneToken token = zone.CreateToken();
```

Comment: Hi I wonder could you expand your answer with some example code as to how I woudl for example return each zone url based on the ZoneID - would it be best in code to have the ZoneID mapped to an Enum class?  Many Thanks

Comment: Updated question with what scenario I was thinking off